# Alternatives for maven dependency tree

Tags: java, maven

When a lot of dependecies need to be resolved/fixed/improved it is nice to have a tool that can analyze dependencies and reports on those.

Most maven tools stop processing with the very first problem. `mvn dependency:tree` is no different. As soon as it finds one missing dependency that needs to be resolved, processing will stop.

NO dependency information will be shown unless 'all' dependencies can be resolved. This makes no sense.

This makes a very tedious process requiring us to run `mvn dependency:tree` for each and every dependency.

Are there tools that are more robust? That will not fail completely for one single missing artifact?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate version of IntelliJ have that functionality, in my opinion it looks /works excelent as an entire IDE, first month is free ;)